# Triangle types program with infile

Tags: java, file-io

So i was writing a program for my computer science class in java and i have no errors but it won't run. I have to do it with an in file also.
The project i am trying to do is here 
http://www.doralacademyprep.org/ourpages/auto/2016/10/28/50508547/C1%20PRG%20JR.pdf

the error message is here

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at GeeImATree.main(GeeImATree.java:58)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GeeImATree {

public static boolean isEquilateral(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC)  {
    if(sideA == sideB && sideB == sideC) {
        return true;
    }
return false;
}
public static boolean isIsosceles(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {
    if(!isEquilateral(sideA,sideB,sideC)){
        return (sideA == sideB || sideB == sideC || sideA == sideC);
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean isRight(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {
    if(!isEquilateral(sideA,sideB,sideC) && !isIsosceles(sideA,sideB,sideC)){
        return ( (sideA*sideA) == (sideB*sideB)+(sideC*sideC) || (sideB*sideB) == (sideA*sideA)+(sideC*sideC) || (sideC*sideC) == (sideA*sideA)+(sideB*sideB));
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean isObtuse(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {
    if (!isEquilateral(sideA,sideB,sideC) && !isIsosceles(sideA,sideB,sideC) && !isRight(sideA,sideB,sideC)) {
        return ( (sideA*sideA) > (sideB*sideB)+(sideC*sideC) || (sideB*sideB) > (sideA*sideA) + (sideC*sideC) || (sideC*sideC) > (sideA*sideA)+(sideB*sideB) );
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean isAcute(double sideA, double b, double c) {
    if(!isEquilateral(sideA,b,c) && !isIsosceles(sideA,b,c) && !isRight(sideA,b,c) && !isObtuse(sideA,b,c)){
        return( (sideA*sideA) < (b*b)+(c*c) || (b*b) < (sideA*sideA) + (c*c) || (c*c) < (sideA*sideA)+(b*b) );
    }
    return false;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    File infile = new File("GEOMETRY.IN"); 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(infile);
    double x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    while(scan.hasNext()) 
    {
        x1 = scan.nextInt();
        y1 = scan.nextInt();
        x2 = scan.nextInt();
        y2 = scan.nextInt();
        x3 = scan.nextInt();
        y3 = scan.nextInt();

        double sideA = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) );
        double sideB = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x3 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y3 - y1, 2) );
        double sideC = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x3 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y3 - y2, 2) );

    System.out.println("a= "+sideA+", b= "+sideB+", c= "+sideC);
    if (isEquilateral(sideA,sideB,sideC))
        System.out.println("Equilateral");
    if (isIsosceles(sideA,sideB,sideC))
        System.out.println("Isosceles");
    if (isRight(sideA,sideB,sideC))
        System.out.println("Right");
    if (isObtuse(sideA,sideB,sideC))
        System.out.println("Obtuse");
    if (isAcute(sideA,sideB,sideC))
        System.out.println("Acute little triangle");
    System.out.println("/n-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_");
    }
scan.close();
}

}
```

In the Geometry.IN file is the following

```
0 0 3.5 1.2 9.85 2
0 0 5 0 5 9
0 0 6 8 8 0
0 0 3 7 1 7
0 0 8 4 8 -4
```

Comment: you should post your file geometry.in

Comment: Ok i added the content of GEOMETRY.IN to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use nextDouble():

```
x1 = scan.nextDouble();
y1 = scan.nextDouble();
x2 = scan.nextDouble();
y2 = scan.nextDouble();
x3 = scan.nextDouble();
y3 = scan.nextDouble();
```

and try with this file:

```
0 0 3,5 1,2 9,85 2
0 0 5 0 5 9
0 0 6 8 8 0
0 0 3 7 1 7
0 0 8 4 8 -4
```

Moreover you have to round multiplication results, for example:

```
public static boolean isRight(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {
    if(!isEquilateral(sideA,sideB,sideC) && !isIsosceles(sideA,sideB,sideC)){
        return ( Math.round(sideA*sideA) == Math.round(sideB*sideB)+Math.round(sideC*sideC) || Math.round(sideB*sideB) == Math.round(sideA*sideA)+Math.round(sideC*sideC) || Math.round(sideC*sideC) == Math.round(sideA*sideA)+Math.round(sideB*sideB));
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: Yess it works now thank you, but one more question is for the second set of values 0 0 5 0 5 9 it returns obtuse but my paper says it should return right triangle

Comment: you have to round numbers, I wrote the isRight method in the answer.

Comment: I added math.round to the double sideA sideB and sideC but now it returns Acute for output 2(it should be right triangle) and isosceles for output three(should be acute)

Comment: ohh i have to round those ok ill try it

Comment: You should round only the multiplication result, not sideA, sideB and sideC numbers.

Comment: Everything is working greatly thank you so much for all the help

Comment: thanks, i just started java around 2 weeks ago in my computer science principles class.

Comment: Ok, it's a great result in only 2 weeks. I suggest you to learn to debug your program, it is really helpful.